# Java output is printing too much, Loop issue

Tags: java, loops

So below is one of four classes (this one is the main) and I have the correct output but the "list of tradebooks" part of the output is printing three times. I believe this is because of a loop but I’m not sure how to fix it. I know there is a lot of code below but I wasn’t sure how much you would need to help me. The output of the code will be below the code to give you a better idea of what I mean.

```
public class BookListGenerator {

    //main
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        //declaring list to hold books
        ArrayList<Textbook> textbooks = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Tradebook> tradebooks = new ArrayList<>();
        //Creates decimal format for output
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00.00");


        // reading file and creating objects
        File fileName = new File("//Users//nbean207//Desktop//Books.txt");

        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileName);
            String type = "",textbook="",name="",ISBN = "",dataMember = "";
            double price= 0;
            int counter = 0;
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                switch (counter) {
                    case 0:
                        type = sc.nextLine();
                        counter++;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        textbook = sc.nextLine();
                        counter++;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        name = sc.nextLine();
                        counter++;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        ISBN = sc.nextLine();
                        counter++;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        price = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
                        counter++;
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        dataMember = sc.nextLine();
                        counter++;
                        break;
                }
                if(counter == 6) {
                    counter = 0;
                    if(type.equals("Textbook")) {
                        Textbook obj = new Textbook(textbook, name, ISBN, price,dataMember);
                        textbooks.add(obj);
                    }
                    else{
                        Tradebook obj = new Tradebook(textbook, name, ISBN, price,dataMember);
                        tradebooks.add(obj);
                    }
                }
            }
            sc.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // reading user input
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true) {
            ArrayList<Textbook> tempTextbooks = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList<Tradebook> tempTradebooks = new ArrayList<>();
            System.out.println("Enter your major; ");
            String major = sc1.nextLine();
            while(true) {
                System.out.println("Enter Course name: (xxx to quit): ");
                String courseName = sc1.nextLine();
                if(courseName.equals("xxx")) {
                    break;
                }
                for(int i=0;i<textbooks.size();i++) {
                    if(textbooks.get(i).dataMember.equals(courseName)) {
                        tempTextbooks.add(textbooks.get(i));
                    }
                }
                for(int j=0;j<tradebooks.size();j++) {
                    if(tradebooks.get(j).dataMember.equals(major)) {
                        tempTradebooks.add(tradebooks.get(j));
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("List of Textbooks: ");
            double textbookprice = 0, tradebookprice = 0;
            for(int i=0;i<tempTextbooks.size();i++) {
                System.out.format("%-10s %-40s %-20s $%-15s \n",          tempTextbooks.get(i).dataMember, tempTextbooks.get(i).title,  tempTextbooks.get(i).author, df.format(tempTextbooks.get(i).getPrice()));
                textbookprice = textbookprice + tempTextbooks.get(i).getPrice();
            }
            System.out.println("Sum of retail book prices:    $"+df.format(textbookprice));
            System.out.println("List of Tradebooks: ");
            for(int j=0;j<tempTradebooks.size();j++) {
                System.out.format("%-50s %-20s $%-15s \n",tempTradebooks.get(j).title,  tempTradebooks.get(j).author, df.format(tempTradebooks.get(j).getPrice()));
                tradebookprice = tradebookprice + tempTradebooks.get(j).getPrice();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output below: Notice that the List of tradebooks part is printing the data 3 times. This is the error i'm having and i'm not sure how to fix it.

```
Enter your major; 
COS
Enter Course name: (xxx to quit): 
COS221
Enter Course name: (xxx to quit): 
COS225
Enter Course name: (xxx to quit): 
BUS398
Enter Course name: (xxx to quit): 
xxx
List of Textbooks: 
COS221     Introduction to Programming with C++     Y. Daniel Liang         $120.99          
COS225     Java Foundations                         John Lewis           $94.59           
BUS398     Excel 2010 Power Programming with VBA    John Walkenbach      $87.99           
Sum of retail book prices: $303.57
List of Tradebooks: 
C++ Primer Plus                                    Stephen Prata        $65.99           
C++ Projects Programming with Text-Based Games     Mike Dawson          $54.95           
Visual C++.Net                                     Don Gosselin         $76.99           
Programming and Object Oriented Design Using Java  Jaime Nino           $98.99           
Object Oriented Data Structures                    Nell Dale            $116.59          
C++ Primer Plus                                    Stephen Prata        $65.99           
C++ Projects Programming with Text-Based Games     Mike Dawson          $54.95           
Visual C++.Net                                     Don Gosselin         $76.99           
Programming and Object Oriented Design Using Java  Jaime Nino           $98.99           
Object Oriented Data Structures                    Nell Dale            $116.59          
C++ Primer Plus                                    Stephen Prata        $65.99           
C++ Projects Programming with Text-Based Games     Mike Dawson          $54.95           
Visual C++.Net                                     Don Gosselin         $76.99           
Programming and Object Oriented Design Using Java  Jaime Nino           $98.99           
Object Oriented Data Structures                    Nell Dale            $116.59
```

Comment: Also paste content of `//Users//nbean207//Desktop//Books.txt` . Looks like your file contains multiple entries.

Comment: After reading each course name, you add the trade books that match the `major` to the `tempTradebooks` list - if the user enters three courses you do this three times (and print out the trade books three times), if the user enters four courses you will print out the trade books four times

Comment: Your tradebooks for loop does not depend on course name input. Move it out from `while (true) {}` loop.

Comment: @hoaz Thanks you helped me resolve the issue, Sorry for such a long question.

Answer (score 0):

Looking aside from any repetitions in the text file(this answer assumes there are no duplicate entries in there):

You print out the tradebooks:

```
           for(int j=0;j<tradebooks.size();j++) {
                if(tradebooks.get(j).dataMember.equals(major)) {
                    tempTradebooks.add(tradebooks.get(j));
                }
            }
```

inside the while-loop.

As such, it is printed every time there is input

Take a look at the commented code:

```
        while(true) {
            System.out.println("Enter Course name: (xxx to quit): ");
            String courseName = sc1.nextLine();
            if(courseName.equals("xxx")) {
                break;
            }
            for(int i=0;i<textbooks.size();i++) {
                if(textbooks.get(i).dataMember.equals(courseName)) {
                    tempTextbooks.add(textbooks.get(i));
                }
            }
            //Right here, every time you add a course, you also add tradebooks to the tempTextBooks-list. Meaning you add it three times.
            for(int j=0;j<tradebooks.size();j++) {
                if(tradebooks.get(j).dataMember.equals(major)) {
                    tempTradebooks.add(tradebooks.get(j));
                }
            }
        }
```

The solution to your problem is to move the for-loop of tradebooks outside the while-loop